# Most visited pages for current user in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I am trying to find out if it's possible to have a KQL for a CSWP that gives me the most visited pages on a site for the current user.

I have been investigating and there are loads of examples for get the most visited pages for a site, but not narrowing to the current logged user.

Many thanks all!

Ignacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in general like "give me the most visited pages" but it is not possible to narrow this down for the current logged in user.

Comment: Yes that's what I have seen so far. Guess there isn't any way either using server code...
But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please mark the answer as answer.